# Why cant I edit post notes on tumblr?

Tags: css, post, edit, tumblr

I'm working on my tumblr blog theme. I'm trying to edit post notes

```
{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}
```

So i've added css code but it doesnt work (I can see post notes, but I cant edit them), here is it:

```
ol.notes {
list-style:none;
color: blue;
margin: 0;
font-size: 3px;
}
ol.notes img { 
display: none;
}
```

I tried to put it on another blog and it works just fine. What I did wrong?

Heres my page: view-source: http://rvnoxx.tumblr.com/

Comment: What do you mean `edit them`. Notes are generated when someone likes or reblogs a post.

Comment: I mean adjust them - see css? Post notes are viewed by clicking on the post, you can see how many people liked, rebloged etc... Basicly they look awfull - i want to add some padding, change size, font color.

Comment: OK, I can add an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know your intended outcome. However I would do a couple of things.

Firstly move the notes block to inside the post block

`{block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}`

Currently it is being rendered outside of it. This will align your content per post.

Secondly I would change this piece of css:

```
.avatar {
   margin: 60px 30px
   ...
}
```

To:

```
.avatar {
   margin: 0;
   ...
}
```

And then I would create this rule:

```
.notes {
   margin-top: 50px;
}
.notes li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Some of this is personal, but that should tidy things up nicely and it's a good start. If you want something more specific please update your question.

This is the result of such css changes:

[image: Result]

Comment: It looks like that for some reason: [link](http://imgur.com/a/9dBzj) (im begginer, sorry), i see you were working on the page, can you send me full code?

Comment: I will try and help. I only edited the code live in the browser. You will need to find the code in your template and update the existing rules, and create new rules if they don't exist already. Everything you need to edit should be inside the `<style>` tags at the top of the template.

Comment: thanks for reply, im not such a begginer :). I was working on the code, you can check my website. The only one problem i have now is that notes dont have padding/margin top, theyre almost sticked to the image. Id appreciate that if you can check it.

Comment: Yes just add this in the style tags `.notes {margin-top: 50px;}`

Comment: I think you need `.notes { margin:50px 0 0 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Looks perfect! Thank you so much. Do you have any idea why after changes this happend [link](http://i.imgur.com/6YT1f3h.png)?

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome for me. However if you do have a different issue, you are better to create a new question.

Comment: I have Chrome and it looks wrong for me. Interesting that in tumblr page "edit code" it looks fine. Ill check this on another computer. If this dont work ill create a new question, thanks